# WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID - most likely the callback was already invoked

Tags: react-native

I got this error when trying to use react-native-wifi-reborn to connect with with

Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 2567 and callID 1283 for  WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID - most likely the callback was already invoked. Args: '[{"code":"unableToConnect","message":"internal error.","domain":"NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain","userInfo":{"NSLocalizedDescription":"internal error."},"nativeStackIOS":["0   wifiborn                            0x0000000100f47024 RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 120","1   wifiborn                            0x0000000100eddad4 __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignat...(truncated)...","2   wifiborn                            0x0000000100e3c55c __77-[WifiManager connectToProtectedSSID:...(truncated)...","3   NetworkExtension                    0x00000001ad1427ac 9AAC742E-D5F7-3619-BC05-EA4F2D8601FB + 505772","4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103f18064 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32","5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103f19d90 _dispatch_client_callout + 20","6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103f2a058 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1040","7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019bb581f8 58500388-BF36-397C-84CF-17315A3445B6 + 668152","8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019bb520d0 58500388-BF36-397C-84CF-17315A3445B6 + 643280","9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019bb511c0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600","10  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001b3139734 GSEventRunModal + 164","11  UIKitCore                           0x000000019e5bf7e4 186C18FD-1082-3811-A761-88E8376C7E69 + 12363748","12  UIKitCore                           0x000000019e5c5054 UIApplicationMain + 168","13  wifiborn                            0x0000000100975950 main + 120","14  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000019b80dcf8 B08AB7C2-64E8-3937-9487-C33D0175FD34 + 7416"]}]'

Simply using this function:

```
  const connectWithWifi = async () => {    
    try {
      //initWifi();
      const data = await WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID(
        ssid,
        password,
        false,
      );
      
      console.log('Connected successfully!', {data});
      setConnected({connected: true, ssid});
    } catch (error) {
      setConnected({connected: false, error: error.message});
      console.log('Connection failed!', {error});
    }
  };
```

someone can Help me?